# Displaying XML Attributes in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am working on showing details of XML attributes in an HTML page using JavaScript. 
My XML file is:

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
```

Code for the HTML is:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    { 
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that nothing is shown in the browser. Is there any problem in the code above?

Comment: What does your Firebug console say? (Or Chrome developer console)

Comment: it gives error as: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
 
home.html, line 12 character 1

Answer (score 3):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

The `true` here gives you an asynchronous HTTP request. It goes off to fetch the document in the background and calls back `onreadystatechange` with `readyState==4` when it has finished. This will probably not have happened by the next statement where you read `responseXML`.

If you want a synchronous request, that will pause the browser and not execute the next line until the document fetch is complete, use `false` instead.

However be aware that the browser ‘hang’ that results is generally considered highly undesirable. Normally, you should use asynchronous requests with a callback function in preference. However such a function would have to use DOM methods to write the content to the page and not the old-school `document.write` which is only available at page load time.

Finally, you're not HTML-escaping the `nodeValue`s you read when writing them to the document, so if there's any `<` or `&` character in the data, you've got problems.

ETA: here's an untested example of doing it asynchronously with DOM methods:

```
<table id="cds"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var xhr= window.XMLHttpRequest? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (this.readyState===4 || this.status===200)
            populateTable(this.responseXML);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'cd_catalog.xml', true);
    xhr.send();

    function populateTable(xml) {
        var table= document.getElementById('cds');
        var cds= xml.getElementsByTagName('CD');
        for (var i= 0; i<cds.length; i++) {
            var row= table.insertRow(-1);

            function getProperty(name) {
                var el= cds[i].getElementsByTagName(name)[0];
                if (el.firstChild)
                    return el.firstChild.data;
                return ''; // allow empty elements
            }
            function addCell(value) {
                row.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
            }

            addCell(getProperty('ARTIST'));
            addCell(getProperty('TITLE'));
        }
    };

</script>
```